# iOS app icon not updating

Tags: ios, app-store, icons

I have an app on App Store. When I try to deploy a build on a device which already has an older retail version of my app installed, it does not update the icon of the app unless the device is restarted. It only happens on FW 6.0+. Does anybody have any ideas on why it is happening or any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: what if you build a your new app version in the simulator? Does it have your new icon?

Comment: No I am using some third libs that don't build on simulator. On the device the problem only occurs if I deploy when the the older version is installed.

Comment: Are you incrementing the version number?

Comment: Yes, I am incrementing it.

Comment: i had the same issue, when i updated my app from the app store. so i guess this is an iOS bug

Comment: Try bumping the bundle version as well.  You can also try using the agvtool command line tool to make sure you're incrementing all the version numbers correctly 'agvtool bump -all'  Before you create a new build with new resources also make sure you perform a project clean 'Shift, Cmd K'.  If the old logo is still in your project, make sure it's not attached to your target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I noticed seemed to work for me last night was to remove any of the files from my project and the Finder folders for the same project that sit next to the main project file. I also had different names for the older and newer ones so I removed the older ones from the plist file too both under icons and iOS 5 icons. Finally I did a Command+Shift+K to clean the project. That all seemed to do it for me on the emulator and on my iPhone I just had to reboot.

Comment: Like I said in the question that the icon updates after device is rebooted. The bug I need to fix is that the icon should update without restarting.

Comment: Agreed the rest fixed without having to reboot. I had done enough on my phone to where I had to but you won't under normal circumstances need to reboot. Doing all those things besides fixed mine and that of my peers on TestFlight who received the build.

Comment: Just tested one more time and it worked on my iPad too. Icon changed on install